# Безопасность банковских карточек

Tags: безопасность, банковские-карты

Я всегда думал, что такие карточки защищены пин кодом, так что если например карточку крадут, то деньги с неё снять не смогут так как пин код ворам не известен.

А недавно узнал что многие интернет магазины никакого пин кода не запрашивают, они запрашивают CVV код, который написан на самой карте сзади. Получается что если кто-то украл карточку он легко может ввести эти данные в интернет магазине и купить себе что-то. Иногда магазины пересылают на сайт банка и от банка поступает SMS с кодом подтверждения. И это реальное решение безопасности, но вот встречал что в некоторых магазинах сразу происходит списание со счёта безо всяких SMS уведомлений. Как вообще такое может быть и почему такое есть?

Существуют ли какие-то варианты карточек где без проверки валидности операции (PIN код, либо SMS подтверждение никаких операций произойти не может). Или может быть какие-то настройки самой карты.

Я честно говоря не специалист по банковской сфере или по картам, наверняка много в этой области не понимаю. Просто хочу для себя прояснить эти моменты с безопасностью.

По поводу уместности этого вопроса на сайте StackOverflow - [Можно ли на сайте задавать вопросы по техническим вопросам банковской сферы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6845/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B).

Comment: Хочется добавить еще к вопросу такую вещь, как PayPass, которая в России позволяет совершать покупки через терминал без ввода пароля до 1000 рублей.

Comment: Ну я понимаю, что если сам держатель карты осознанно соглашается на такие операции то тут всё нормально. А если ситуация когда я хочу все операции проводить через подтверждение паролем или SMS? Есть ли у меня такая возможность.

Comment: А некоторые интернет-магазины (например, Amazon) даже и CVV-код не запрашивают. :) По сути вопроса - нет, таких карточек нет.

Comment: @Yaant тогда вопрос почему нет? я просто непонимаю, карточки существуют столько лет, столько есть технологий безопасности, столько времени, сил, деней тратится на безопасность банковских систем, почему они не могут сделать такую элементарную безопасность для пользователей?

Comment: Имхо, проще обратиться в службу поддержка банка и получить квалифицированную консультацию с информацией, как говорится, из первых рук :)

Comment: Pin код по Сети **никогда** не запрашивают. Только CVV (если запрашивают вообще)

Comment: Во-первых, потому что банки не могут сами придумывать правила обработки транзакций по картам, а обязаны работать по правилам платежных систем.  А, во-вторых, очевидно, существующий уровень безопасности считается достаточным.

Comment: хотя нужно быть знатным васяном чтобы не заметить потерю карты, сейчас владелец карты может заблокировать ее за считанные секунды. Да и смс оповещения по любым транзакциям можно подключить.

Comment: Впрочем, многие банки позволяют выставить лимиты на расходные операции. Ничего не мешает выставить все лимиты в 0, и непосредственно перед покупкой выставлять нужный лимит. От большинства сценариев несанкционированного списания денег это защитит (однако, не ото всех)

Comment: Наверное, единственное, что Вы можете сделать для обеспечения безопасности своей банковской карты - это не давать её другим в руки, даже при оплате в магазине сейчас чаще всего не требуется передавать карту продавцу, покупатель может сам вставить карту в POS-терминал и достать тоже сам. И не показывать её другой стороной (не светить CVV-код). Но и эти действия ничего не гарантируют... ) Пожалуй, это всё, что от Вас зависит... ) Ну, или можете ещё в интернет-банкинге выставить лимиты на суммы  операций, но это так, сомнительная мера)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или администрированию. Вопрос лучше задать на специализированном сайте продвинутых пользователей банковских услуг вроде banki.ru

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ а может вместо закрытия развернуть вопрос, так чтобы обсуждение перешло в русло обсуждения инженерных проблем, что нужно делать программистам для того, чтобы усложнить жизнь мошенникам?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Я был бы только за!

Comment: Вообще за проведение платежей отвечает платежная система, карточка которой у вас выпущена(чаще всего это Visa/MasterCard). Операции могут быть подтверждаемыми(пинкод\смс) и не подтверждаемыми(номер карты + cvv). Считается, что согласно протоколам платежных систем не подтверждаемые операции достаточно легко оспорить(сам никогда не пробовал). 
Часто в приложении банка можно настроить невозможность проведения не подтверждаемых операций. У Тинькова была галочка, запретить операции через интернет(сейчас не смог найти в мобильном клиенте).

Comment: @Viktorov спасибо, очень полезная информация, про это я и спрашивал, спрошу у своего банка есть ли такое.

Comment: @Viktorov что-то нигде не нашёл в интеренете про отключение неподтверждаемых операций, в данном случае меня интересует Сбербанк

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин в веб интерфейсе настройки -> лимиты расходов на переводы и платежи -> включить подтверждение звонком

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин перед покдлючением обязатеьлно посоветуйтесь со службой поддержки, а то возможно я вам что-то не то насоветовал)

Comment: Уиии, кардинг на SO ;)

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что здесь на сайте собрались специалисты по программированию, с не по финансовым операциям. Если вам нужен этот вопрос чтобы получить правильный ответ, вы очевидно на по адресу. Если вам хочется просто пообщаться с неспециалистами, тогда окей. Но я бы предупредил будущих читателей о том, что лучше узнавать информацию от профессионалов.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или системному администрированию.

Comment: существует тучу банков, и они не хотят знать о других банках. для этого существует платежная система. каждая операция внутри банка(и третьесторонных процессоров) проходит внутри банка без  платежной системы. другие операции проходят через платежную систему.  такие операции не требуют никаких подтверждений.  подтверждение есть у тех банков, кто имеет фронт-офис с онлайн экварингом.

Comment: то есть операции подтверждения пинкода будут пройти онлайн, после чего разрешат взаимодействие.  некоторые сервисы перенаправляют на страницу банка, потому что он так ЗАХОТЕЛИ, чтобы пользователь доверил, иначе ничего не купит на этом сервисе. А гигантам все равно, ты в любом случае передашь данные карты.  на магнитных картах пароль хранится на магнитной полосе, кстати.

Comment: сейчас можно оспаривать решение о транзакции, но это очень долго и почти всегда клиент проигрывает.  для этого я рекомендую вам пользовать вируальными картами, кидаете сколько нужно и оплачиваете сервис.  в телефоне PayPas используете подмену данных карт.  не носите карту собой, как я уже 2 года. 
через некоторые платехные системы операции проходят до 45 дней(например visa - jcb). то есть по сути вы можете купить товар с экваера VISA, а деньги спишутся через 45 дней.

Comment: другие банкоматы не имеют онлайн подключение и в раз в сутки отправляют данные, они в осномнов в бедных странах. ты за ночь можешь снять по 100 баксов в N раз, а утром с карты будет списано минус 100N баксов.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин каждая платежная система обменивается специальными отчетами, который содержит транзакции и в итоге кто кому сколько должен.  там как раз есть все данные, кроме cvc и пин кода.  так как эти данные нужны только во время авторизации на стороне фронта. ПС делится на фронофис и на бэкофис

Answer (score 0):

Вывод прост, надо делать так, чтоб карточку не воровали, а если и своруют, то не смогут воспользоваться. С банкоматом все ок, без пинкода никуда, терминалы оплаты вроде так-же. А вот чтоб и через интернет не сняли денег, то стереть сами три цифры. Вы их все равно знаете, либо где-то глубоко в чулане хранится бумажка с пинкодом и этими цифрами. Это те меры, которые могут зависеть только от вас.

Все остальное это настройки вашего банковского аккаунта. Если есть возможность выписывать себе виртуальные кредитные карты, то круть, создал, оплатил, удалил. Если есть какие-то дополнительные меры защиты, то стоит их включить.

Что касается интернет магазинов, то пользоваться только надежными. Постепенно всех обяжут использовать 3d secure или некий аналог.

Ну а пока, имеем то что имеем, ничего удобнее не придумали еще. А удобство несет некие риски.

Comment: ЕМНИП, стирание CVV делает карточку формально недействительной

Comment: Нет. Она будет не менее действительной. Аппараты считывают магнитную ленту либо чип. Для интернет магазинов даже физическое существование карты не обязательно. Более того, иногда случаются опечатки и три цифры вовсе не те, которые должны быть, но карта вполне себе работает.

Comment: Я же говорю — **формально** недействительной, а не физически нерабочей, это разные вещи. Это как отсутствие личной подписи в специальном поле тоже делает её недействительной.

Comment: Для банковских карт нет такого понятия "формально недействительная".

Comment: Тем не менее мне лично отказывал в обслуживании кассир, когда я хотел оплатить покупку картой, на которой не было моей подписи. Мне нейчас лениво гуглить конкретные правила банков, но ваше мнение точно расходится с действительностью — карту могут посчитать недействительной, и у меня это случалось.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет подпись к этим цифрам? На моих картах нет никаких полей для подписей.

Comment: Рад за вашу карту, но то, что вы рассказываете, относится далеко не ко всем картам

Comment: Это же касается и вас.

Comment: Кроме того для оплаты не всегда требуется CVV, на некоторых торговых площадках достаточно номера карты и expiration date.